# List all the files in firebase storage date wise and zip it using cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I want to achieve the functionality using cloud function in javascript - I know how to list all the files from the storage and loop through it

```
const ref = admin.storage().bucket();
const [result] = await ref.getFiles({ prefix: `${bucketName}/` });
```

But I want to list all the files based on the Time in Descending order. And after doing that I want to leave only the first 5 files and zip the remaining files in the same structure as in storage and save the zip separately in my storage

Comment: Hello, what did you try apart from listing the files? Did you search for a Node.js library for zippping that can be used in a Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No I haven't tried it yet. Will search for it